# How to manage permission on same URLs but different IDs

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, middleware, laravel-5.8

There are many report managers of a application
Each report manager have access of reports.
For example, One report manager have access of 3,4,5 reports and other have access of 2,3,7

```
Route::get('report/{id}', 'ReportController@index');
```

How to manage permissions on the basis of IDs in middleware

**What I did :**

Created a middleware to check if the current user is report manager then in

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth_report'], 'roles' => ['report']], function () {
    Route::get('report/{id}', 'ReportController@index');
}
```

But it gives access to all reports to any report manager.
How to manage permission on the basis of IDS